# How to get the src attribute of an image with Puppeteer? I am getting 'Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am working with Puppeteer and trying to download an image.
On Chrom dev tool console this returns what I want:

```
document.querySelector('.photo img').getAttribute('src')
```

but with Puppeteer evaluate function the same code :

```
let imageSrc = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return document.querySelector('.photo img').getAttribute('src');
});
```

throws an error:

```
error:  Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: The element may be added to the pae after your try to get it. Maybe `waitForSelector` before `evaluate` can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you have to wait for the element.

```
await page.waitForSelector('.photo img');
const imgSrc = await page.$eval('.photo img', (el) => el.getAttribute('src'));
```

or

```
await page.waitForSelector('.photo img');
const imgSrc = await page.$eval('.photo img', (el) => el.src); // Not sure if gonna work
```